# Using vuelidate with Vue 3 : Decorators Issue with composition API (`<script setup>`)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vuelidate

I am doing vue upgrade from vue 2 to vue 3. There's an error in @Component decorator called

*"Decorators are not valid here.ts(1206)
(alias) Component(options: Vue.ComponentOptionsBase<Vue, any, any, any, any, any, any, any, string, {}, {}, string> & ThisType & ThisType): (target: VC) => VC (+1 overload)
import Component"*

This is my code.

```
<script setup>
  import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
  import apiService from "@/shared/services/apiService";
  import { validationMixin } from "vuelidate";
  import { required, email } from "vuelidate/lib/validators";
  import dirtyValidatorService from "@/shared/services/dirtyValidatorService";

  @Component({
    mixins: [validationMixin],
    validations: {
      userName: {
        required,
      },
      email: {
        required,
        email,
      },
    },
  })
  export const ForgotPassword = () => {
    userName: string = "";
    email: string = "";
    showSuccessMessage: boolean = false;
    showErrorMessage: boolean = false;
    dirtyValidatorRefNo: number = 0;
    dirtyValidationConfirmation: boolean = false;
    errorMessage: string = "";
    created = () => {
      this.dirtyValidatorRefNo = dirtyValidatorService.setInitialModel(
        this.dirtyValidatorRefNo,
        { userName: this.userName, email: this.email }
      );
    }
    SendForgotPasswordEmail = (isFormInvalid: boolean) =>{
      if (!isFormInvalid) {
        this.$store.dispatch("storeIsBusyValue", true);
        apiService
          .sendPostRequest("Account", "ResetPasswordEmail", {
            userName: this.userName,
            email: this.email,
          })
          .then((response) => {
            this.showErrorMessage = !response.data.isSuccess;
            this.showSuccessMessage = response.data.isSuccess;
            this.errorMessage = !response.data.isSuccess
              ? response.data.message
              : "";
            this.$store.dispatch("storeIsBusyValue", false);
          });
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

If anyone knows to solve this, please mention it. Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a [different documentation for using *vuelidate* with Vue 3](https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/#alternative-syntax-composition-api).

Adapting the example from the documentation to match your use case and using `<script setup>` should look like :

```
<script setup>
import { reactive } from 'vue'
import { useVuelidate } from '@vuelidate/core'
import { required, email } from '@vuelidate/validators'
// And other imports

const state = reactive({
  userName: '',
  email: ''
})

const rules = {
  userName: { required },
  email: { required, email }
}

const v$ = useVuelidate(rules, state)
</script>
```

Comment: It seems okay. But there's an another issue with `(isFormInvalid: boolean)` . The error is   **Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files.ts(8010)** near boolean keyword. Are there any solution for it?

Comment: Try changing `<script setup>` to `<script setup lang="ts">`. I recommend you thouroughly read [Vue 3 docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html) as there are a lot of differences with Vue 2. (Don't forget to toggle the "Composition API" switch at the top of the navigation menu)

Comment: I have changed it also. But the issue was not be solved. However, I appreciate your effort. Thanks for it!

Answer (score 1):

Please check this - [Migrating from vue2 with property-decorator and class style syntax to vue3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72742468/migrating-from-vue2-with-property-decorator-and-class-style-syntax-to-vue3)

I was faced the same issue. I have a huge vue2 project that full built with "vue-property-decorator" and when I decided migrate to vue3 I couldn't do it because "vue-property-decorator" is depricated and doesn't support vue3.

Here is an issue about it on their GitHub - [#294 Vue 3.0 support](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator/issues/294)

So I had to migrate to vue 2.7 (it allows to write new components using Composition API) and manually rewrite all my project to Composition API, then I was able to migrate it to vue 3.

But check the first link I provided in the beginning. Seems like they found a way to use "vue-property-decorator" with vue 3.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. This will help to solve my problem. Regards!

Comment: vue-property-decorator now suggests vue-facing-decorator in its deprecation notice. It’s worked well for us in migrating our class components to Vue 3

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try `vue-facing-decorator` instead of `vue-class-component` or `vue-property-decorator`. It’s now the suggested alternative in the deprecation notices of both packages.

We’ve found it effective in migrating our class components to Vue 3.

https://medium.com/@robert.helms1/vue-2-to-vue-3-with-class-components-cdd6530a2b2a

Comment: In this article, there is a note that mentioning  **in vue 3, class components would be even more supported than in Vue 2** But I noticed in vue migration document, we are not forced to used class component in vue 3. Is it right?

Comment: @KanchanaKariyawasam that statement about being “more supported” is talking about how long ago the Vue 3 specs included a native Class API which would support class components without the need for any other package BUT (as mentioned in the article) that idea was abandoned which means we still need to use a package like vue-facing-decorator for class components.

Comment: @KanchanaKariyawasam core Vue 3 only officially uses the Options API and the Composition API for components, not class components